# Universal/general algebra: altering group operation definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, universal-algebra

Exercise 2.2.2 of [An Invitation to Universal Algebra](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Egbergman/245/3.2.pdf) says:

> If $G$ is a group, let us define an operation $\delta_G$ on $|G|$
> by $\delta_G(x, y) = x · y^{−1}$. Does the pair $G' = (|G|, \delta_G)$ determine the group $(|G|, ·, {}^{−1}, e)$? (I.e., if $G_1$ and $G_2$ yield the same pair, $G'_1 = G'_2$, must $G_1 = G_2$? Some students have asked whether by “=” I here mean “$\cong$”.
> No, I mean “=”.)

So far I have been able to find an algorithm to recover $G$ from $G'$ (if one exists, which  I doubt). I did try the other way around for some simple examples. For $\mathbb{Z}_2$, the group is unaffected by the $\delta$ operation since both members are already their own inverse. After applying the $\delta$ operation to $\mathbb{Z}_3$, there is no right identity, so it isn’t even a group. Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 5):

The group $G=(|G|,\cdot,x^{-1},e)$ is recoverable from $G':=(|G|,\delta_G)$ when $\delta_G(x,y):=x\cdot y^{-1}$.

To recover the identity $e$ of $G$ from $\delta_G$, observe that $e$ is the unique element in the image of the function $\delta_G(x,x)$.

Once you have $e$, recover the inverse using the formula $x^{-1} = \delta_G(e,x)$.

Once you have the inverse, recover the multiplication using the formula $x\cdot y = \delta_G(x,y^{-1})$.

In particular, if $G_1'=G_2'$, then $|G_1|=|G_2|$ and $\delta_{G_1}=\delta_{G_2}$. Recovering the identity element by the above formula leads to $e_1=e_2$. Then recover inverse and multiplication to get ${x}^{-1_1}={x}^{-1_2}$ and $x\cdot_1 y = x\cdot_2 y$, so $G_1=(|G_1|,\cdot_1,x^{-1_1},e_1)=(|G_2|,\cdot_2,x^{-1_2},e_2)=G_2$.